# How can i change text field without a button action

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

For objective-C and iOS development, Is it possible to change textfield when user pushes a key.

For ex : User pushes the key 'k' but sees 'a' in the textfield. (the same usage in PeterAnswers.com )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think this is possible. You should take a look at this `UITextField` delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

You should be able to manipulate the input string before it is displayed in the actual textfield. A specific implementation of your question could be:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    // if the user entered x...
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"x"]){
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@a", textField.text]; // ...append the previous string with the 'a' token instead!
        return NO; // return NO to make sure the x isn't put in the textField
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make sure to link the `UITextField` delegate to the class where you put this code.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW9) method of the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Totally. Look at the apple documentation on UITextFieldDelegate.  Everything you need is right there.